# How to subset rows in table1 function in R?

Tags: r, subset

I want to make a table using the same data source and columns but creating a subset of data for one of the columns (excluding "Large").

```
table1::label(data$Fraction != "Large")<-"Fraction all except large"
table1::label(data$Fraction)<-"Fraction all"
table1::table1(~Fraction+
               ~Fraction
                 | Location, data = data, transpose = F)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "data" is a data.frame or similar (your example is not clear there), subset your data first:

```
datasubset <- subset(data, data$Fraction != "Large")
```

Only then plug it into table1 for formatting/exporting or whatever you're doing with that.